# Cannot persist the object

Tags: c#, devexpress, xaf

We got an error from my application when an object is used and modified in different application that time i got this issue.Can anybody please give the better solution to resolve this issue.

Error:
System.ArgumentException: Cannot persist the object. It was modified or deleted (purged) by another application.

Thanks

Comment: send a clone instead of the real object and have an event when the clone is modified?

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown to avoid losing changes introduced by another user. You can turn off this behavior via the [OptimisticLockingAttribute](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/clsDevExpressXpoOptimisticLockingAttributetopic). In this case, the last user who introduced changes will win. Please refer to the [Optimistic Concurrency Control](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/CustomDocument2106) help topic for additional information.
If you do not wish to lose changes, you can catch [LockingException](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/clsDevExpressXpoDBExceptionsLockingExceptiontopic) and perform the required operations instead of throwing the exception.

Related discussion:
[How to obtain an available object and lock it to prevent other users from modifying it](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T220295)